# Delete Contact lastname

Tags: trigger

This is mycode if i deleted the contact record delete the last name in Contact_Names__c in Account

```
trigger ContactNamesOnAccount on Contact (after update, after insert) {    
    Set<id> accIdList = new Set<id>();
    for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
        accIdList.add(con.accountid);
    }

    List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
    List<String> names = new List<String>;

    for(Account acc : [Select id, Contact_Names__c, (Select LastName From Contacts) From Account Where Id In : accIdList]){
        for(Contact con : acc.contacts){
            if(con.LastName != null){
                /* add name to list */
                names.add(con.LastName);
            }
        }

        /* update name separating ', '  */
        acc.Contact_Names__c = String.join(names, ', ');;
        accUpdateList.add(acc);

        /* clear list to add new account contact names */
        names.clear();
    }    
    update accUpdateList;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing here? You have included code that has no relationship with a Delete DML operation, as you have hinted in your statement of this question. Please elaborate more on how you would like to community to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse your existing code, just that you will have to add an additional event of after delete to your trigger. And make below minor changes in the code

Your complete code would be

```
trigger ContactNamesOnAccount on Contact (after update, after insert, after delete) {    
    Set<id> accIdList = new Set<id>();

    if(Trigger.isAfter && (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)){
        for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
            accIdList.add(con.accountid);
        }
    } else if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete){
        for(Contact con : Trigger.old){
            accIdList.add(con.accountid);
        }
    } 

    List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
    List<String> names = new List<String>;

    for(Account acc : [Select id, Contact_Names__c, (Select LastName From Contacts) From Account Where Id In : accIdList]){
        for(Contact con : acc.contacts){
            if(con.LastName != null){
                /* add name to list */
                names.add(con.LastName);
            }
        }

        /* update name separating ', '  */
        acc.Contact_Names__c = String.join(names, ', ');;
        accUpdateList.add(acc);

        /* clear list to add new account contact names */
        names.clear();
    }    
    update accUpdateList;
}
```

Comment: can you plz write code in apex only for delete

Comment: Thanks it is working